# Unable to complete action Internal Error - An unexpected error occurred and the operation could not be completed. Error Code: 6EA18A9E

Tags: tableau-api

I'm currently working on the Google's Advanced Data Analytics Professional Certificate, and im on the Data Viz part. I'm currently using and learning Tableau (I've downloaded the Tableau's Desktop version 2023.3). The part im doing right now is creating data vizzes.

I've been given a dataset of NOAA lightning strikes in the US and need create some vizzes using that dataset, about how many lighting strikes happened in which states and in which years and dates.

The dataset consists of 4 columns, Date, Number of strikes, X coord, Y coord. I placed the Avg of X coord & Y coord on columns and rows respectively which gave me a map of the pinpoint location of the average taken of all the X & Y coords. It came out in the state Arkansas.

Next i placed the Date column in the Filters tab to filter some years (There are only 4 years provided in the dataset & I selected them all following the video).

Now the problem popped out on the next step, which was placing the Date column in the Pages field. I'm going to attach the snapshot of the error and the whole Worksheet.

[The errors snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i46hn.jpg)

I'm fairly new to Tableau, i tried copying the error and went to Tableau's support and couldn't find a working solution. One of the solution said that using 2020 or older version can cause this error but mine is 2023. Idk what to do. If anyone has came across this kind of error before, please help a fellow out :')

Answer (score 0):

You are asking Tableau to show every date associated with the average of all the X & Y coords in your data and it is unable to do so.

Make sure your  X & Y custom "coords" are ready to be used as ***[geographic roles](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/plotting-geographic-data-using-custom-longitude-and-latitude)*** and because you only have four columns I would say try to bring `[Date]` to the *Detail* section on the Marks Pane. Then bring `[Date]` out again to the *Tooltip* section of the Marks Pane.

There should not be a dot on the map for every `[Date]` and the date it happened should show up when you hover each dot. Format as necessary.